# How to set an image to strecth and fill the screen? (the screen's diveded into 2)

Tags: android, css

So, I have a screen that's divided into 2. On the top half of the screen I have an image and on the bottom half of it I have a text. I can't get my image to fill the screen correctly no matter what. It always ends with a blank space either on the top of the image or on the sides (as in the following photos):[Blank sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI4m1.jpg),[Blank top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiF75.png). I'd appreciate if someone could help me out on this matter.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried to use align on it and gravity without succes. I didn't use scaleType.

Comment: Can you post the code for your layout?

Comment: I edited the post and posted the layout's code too, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

should work. You can find the other possible values for `scaleType` [here.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. It works both with android:scaleType="centerCrop" and android:scaleType="fitXY" . I totally forgot about this one.

Comment: @StelianTeodor you are welcome. You can mark the question as answered. Regards